# Why after save *Occur* buffer I can't edit editable file?

Tags: text-editing, occur

Emacs 26.1, Windows 10 (64 bit)

I open file `trace.log`. User occur to find text. Save *occur* buffer to file `NXS_ETH.txt`. Do some manipulations. See screenshots. But I can't edit EDITABLE file.

Here steps:
[image]

Save *occur* buffer to file:
[image]

[image]

File is EDITABLE (not read-only).

[image]

Remove Face and text properties:
[image]
[image]

I press "a" but char "a" not show in buffer. I get message on minibuffer:

```
a is undefined
```

What is this?

[image]

To fix this I reopen file `NXS_ETH.txt` and then success edit buffer.

Why I can't input any text after save *occur* buffer to the file?

Comment: @Drew As I said the file is NOT read only. I also try C-x C-q but it not help. Only M-x text-mode is fixed problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *occur* buffer is in `occur` mode. This mode doesn't allow you to edit text. After you save it, you need to change to a different mode. `M-x text-mode` should do what you need.

Comment: You can just use `C-x C-q` to toggle read-only in an `*Occur*` buffer, to make it editable.

Comment: @Drew that's not enough, because the buffer is still in Occur mode. `C-x C-q` makes it editable, but there are no self-inserting keys in the occur-mode map. The warning Emacs reports is not "Buffer is read-only", it is "a is not defined".

Comment: @Drew you could use `e` to switch to `occur-edit` mode, but then the changes are made in the original source file. @Alexei wants to make changes in a saved copy of the `occur` buffer.

Comment: Oh, right. You can delete text but there's no self-inserting. Similar problem to making `*Help*` writable (but worse). Makes such buffers less usable than they used to be. But yes, all you need to do is change the mode (or use `C-q` ;-)).